# What should I use to make API requests to my node back end from my React front end?

Tags: reactjs, backend

How should I be making API requests from a React front end? I'm new to front ends and more specifically react and I am just unsure what do use to make the requests? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any decent ajax library should do the job. Most people are comfortable using [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), but you can use whatever you're most familiar with, including:

- [whatwg-fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch)
- [superagent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/)

You can even use plain "vanilla" JavaScript:

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.open("POST", "path/to/api", true);
r.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return;
  alert("Success: " + r.responseText);
};
r.send("banana=yellow");
```